# Star staircase confusion

Tags: java

OK I'm embarrassed I have to ask this but I'm stuck so here we go, please nudge me in the right direction.
We need to create this using a nested loop:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Here's what I came up with.

```
int row,col; 
for(row = 5; row >= 1; row--)
{ 
    for (col = 0; col < 5 - row; col++)
        println("");

    for(col = 5; col >= row; col--)
        print("*");
}
```

It ALMOST works but it prints spaces between each row and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Comment: Why do you do println("") in a loop?

Comment: my logic was so that it goes to the next row and prints the next row of stars there.

Comment: Yes, you want it to go down one row, so that it is one line below the next line.  You don't want a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only want to use one inner loop, to print each row of stars.  Then print a newline at the end of each row:

```
int row, col;
for(row = 1; row <= 5; row++) {
    for(col = 0; col < row; col++) {
        print("*");
    }
    println("");
}
```

Comment: success! Thanks!  I must be burning myself out over thinking this stuff!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just one `println("");` at the end of the loop instead of looping that statement?  You only need the one new line per row of stars.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col <= row; col++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: Why did you rewrite the code?  His variable names were slightly more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simplify it?

```
int row, col;
for(row=0; row<5; row++) {
    for(col=0;col<=row;col++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Print one row at a time, and then print the line-end

---

For the sake of only one I/O operation, a function may be a suitable approach:

```
public String starStarcase(int rows) {
    int row, col;
    String str="";
    for(row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for(col = 0; col <= row; col++) {
            str += "*";
        }
        str += "\n";
    }
    return str;
}
```

To print the result:

```
System.out.println(starsStaircase(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it should work:

```
for(int j = 0; j < row; j++){
    for(int i = 1; i <= row; i++){
        System.out.print(i < row-j ? " " : "#");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```